# How do I find the length from a tetrahedron vertex to its face using vector methods?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose the length of each edge of the regular tetrahedron is $x$ and **a**, **b**, **c** represents the position vectors from the origin O and the points A, B, C. How can I find the distance from a vertex to its opposite face?

I thought I had to use the concept of scalar products etc. to do this question, but my solution does not involve any vectors and is largely geometric. The answer does not match.

My thought process:

1. Since it's a regular tetrahedron, all sides are equilateral triangles.
2. I divided the base of the tetrahedron (one triangle) into 3 areas using the centroid of the face to obtain 3 isosceles triangles.
3. Let distance from vertex to centroid of on triangular face of the tetrahedron by $k$. Since I know the length of the longest side of the isosceles triangle is $x$, I use sine rule of $\frac{\sin(30)}{k} = \frac{\sin(120)}{x}$ to get my $k$ value in terms of $x$.
4. Now I have a new triangle with hypotenuse $x$ and base $k$. I use Pythagoras theorem to get my answer.

Could someone show me where my thought process has gone wrong or show me the direction I should approach this question instead?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The strategy looks right in principle to me. I haven't checked your use of the law of sines in steps 2 and 3. YOu don't need it if you just find the altitude of the base equilateral triangle and remember that the centroid is $2/3$ of the way from a vertex. You can finish the work and answer your own question here.

Comment: @EthanBolker strangely I've checked my work through and through, but it just doesn't match the answer..and it's the odd ball solution here since the task was to use vector methods instead of geometric ones.

Comment: Do you mean points $A,B,C,D$? Or, is the origin one of the vertices?

Comment: If you edit the question to post your actual work (not just your strategy) and the answer you think you should have gotten we may be able to help. I find the "vector methods" requirement odd since the answer does not depend on the position of the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use an orthogonal reference, with $O$ at the origin, $\mathbf a$ along the first axis (unit vector $\hat i$), $\mathbf b$ in the  $\hat i\hat j$ plane, and $\mathbf c$ with components along all three axes. Since we know the angle between vectors is $\pi/3$, we can write 
$$\mathbf a=x\hat i\\
\mathbf b=x\cos\frac{\pi}{3}\hat i+x\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\hat j\\
\mathbf c=\alpha \hat i+ \beta \hat j+\gamma\hat k
$$
The distance from $C$ to the plane $ABO$ is $\gamma$. We can now use $$\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf c=x^2\cos\frac{\pi}{3}\\ \mathbf b\cdot\mathbf c=x^2\cos\frac{\pi}{3}\\ \mathbf c\cdot\mathbf c=x^2$$ to calculate all the components.
From the first equation $x\alpha=x^2\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $$\alpha=x/2$$ From the second equation $$x\frac{1}{2}\alpha+x\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\beta=x^2\frac{1}{2}$$ This yields $$\beta=\frac{x}{2\sqrt 3}$$
The third equation is $$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=x^2$$
Plugging in the previous values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we get $$\gamma=x\sqrt\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: How were you able to get the values for ac, bc and cc? And what does cc mean?

Comment: I should put a dot between the letters. It's the dot product. Note that $\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf v=uv\cos\theta$, where theta is the angle between $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re supposed to use “vector methods,” here’s a way to approach this. The vector $\mathbf n=\mathbf a\times\mathbf b$ is orthogonal to the face $\triangle{OAB}$. The distance of $C$ from this face is then the length of the projection of $\mathbf c$ onto $\mathbf n$, namely, $${|\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf c|\over\|\mathbf n\|}={|\mathbf a \times\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf c| \over \|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b\|}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Put the tetrahedron in four-dimensional space, with vertices at the points $ (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$.  The edges are $\sqrt{2}$.  The centre of one side is $(1/3,1/3,1/3,0)$, and its distance from $(0,0,0,1)$ is $\sqrt{4/3}$.  So your answer is $\sqrt{2/3}$

Comment: What do you mean by the center of 1 side is (1/3,1/3,1/3,0)? Is it the centroid of a triangular face? Also, how did you get from sqrt(4/3) to sqrt(2/3)?

Comment: Yes, the centroid of the triangle with vertices (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0) and (0,0,1,0).  The edges, for example (1,0,0,0)-(0,1,0,0)=(1,-1,0,0), have length sqrt(2), so to get your answer for a tetrahedron with edges length 1, I need to divide sqrt(4/3) by sqrt(2)

Comment: However, what is the reason for the division? Wouldn't the distance from the vertex to the centroid give you the answer directly? I'm very interested in this approach of solving but I'm unsure of the explanation.

Comment: The edges have length sqrt(2), so the tetrahedron is sqrt(2) too big.  I need to scale it down by that factor.

Comment: Why is sqrt(2) considered too big? and what happens if you don't scale it?